# Kotlin How to integrate/merge with same value in the List of data class

Tags: list, kotlin, arraylist, collections

I want to merge same "startime" to one (step, distance and calorie) in the list, how can I to do this.

```
 var listNewStepData = arrayListOf<NewStepData>()
```

data class

```
data class NewStepData (
    val startTime: String?,
    val endTime: String?,
    val step: Int? = 0,
    val distance: Int? = 0,
    val calorie: Int? = 0
)
```

this is sample

```
NewStepData(startTime=2020-04-14T00:00:00.000Z, endTime=2020-04-14T00:00:00.000Z, step=4433, distance=0, calorie=0)
NewStepData(startTime=2020-04-14T00:00:00.000Z, endTime=2020-04-15T00:00:00.000Z, step=0, distance=0, calorie=1697)
NewStepData(startTime=2020-04-14T00:00:00.000Z, endTime=2020-04-14T00:00:00.000Z, step=0, distance=2436, calorie=0)
NewStepData(startTime=2020-04-15T00:00:00.000Z, endTime=2020-04-15T00:00:00.000Z, step=5423, distance=0, calorie=0)
NewStepData(startTime=2020-04-15T00:00:00.000Z, endTime=2020-04-16T00:00:00.000Z, step=0, distance=0, calorie=1715)
NewStepData(startTime=2020-04-15T00:00:00.000Z, endTime=2020-04-15T00:00:00.000Z, step=0, distance=3196, calorie=0)
```

I want to get this

```
NewStepData(startTime=2020-04-14T00:00:00.000Z, endTime=2020-04-15T00:00:00.000Z, step=4433, distance=2436, calorie=1697)
NewStepData(startTime=2020-04-15T00:00:00.000Z, endTime=2020-04-16T00:00:00.000Z, step=5423, distance=3196, calorie=1715)
```

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `groupBy { }` for your list. It will return a map of your grouping variable type to lists of your original type. And then, use `flatMap` to aggregate your data.

I assume that you take maximum end date which is `maxBy` and sum of distances, and steps which you need `sumBy` for, and calories which `sumByDouble` is the best choice.

Here's the sample code:

```
var grouped = listNewStepData.groupBy { it.startTime }.flatMap { entry -> NewStepData(startTime = entry.key,
        endTime = entry.value.maxBy { item -> item.endTime },
        step = entry.value.sumBy { item -> item.step },
        distance = entry.value.sumBy { item -> item.distance },
        calorie = entry.value.sumByDouble { item -> item.calorie })
}
```

Comment: endTime type is String use maxby is return NewStepData? so could Type mismatch

Comment: @leaf76 Agreed. There needs to be a default value provided.